# How do I prove $2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2 + 2^3 +\cdots + 2^{d-1} \le n - 1$ $\space$ if $\space$ $d = \lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor$?

Tags: inequality

I was given this inequality in university, me and my friends can't solve it, hope someone here can explain me:

$2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2 + 2^3 + \cdots + 2^{d-1} \le n - 1$ $\space$ if $\space$ $d = \lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor$.

Comment: What happens if you add 1 to both sides?

Answer (score 2):

Observe that the series $\sum_{k=0}^d 2^k$ is a geometric series which has the closed form $(2^{d}-1)/(2-1) = 2^{d}-1$.

Because $d = \lfloor \log_2n \rfloor$, we have

$$d = \lfloor \log_2n \rfloor \leq \log_2n$$

by definition of the floor function. Raising both sides of the inequality by 2 and subtracting 1 thereafter, we deduce that

$$2^d - 1 \leq 2^{\log_2n} - 1 = n -1 $$

as desired.

Comment: I added some steps and improved readability.

Answer (score 1):

First, remember that
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}ar^i=a\frac{1-r^n}{1-r}, \qquad r\neq 1.
$$
So, in particular,
$$
1+2+2^2+\cdots+2^{d-1}=\frac{1-2^d}{1-2}=2^d-1.
$$